# HERE iOS sdk: Polygon lineColor change fails at runtime

Tags: here-api

I am using HERE iOS SDK and I am trying to change the style of a test polygon, e.g. background and line colour.
While setting the background colour to white would work:

```
let polygon = NMAMapPolygon()
polygon.fillColor = UIColor.white
```

changing the line colour wouldn't. :(

```
polygon.lineColor = UIColor.red
```

Update: I tested the same behaviour with NMAMapCircle - fill colour changes immediately, line colour doesn't...

Can anybody help me with that? I don't get a runtime/debug error or anything, it just doesn't react.

Comment: Are you using the latest sdk version. Please provide your mobile version and sdk version you are using.

Comment: Xcode 10.1, framework NMAKit 3.9.0.15

Answer (score 0):

We rechecked 3.9 with the following code.
Everything works perfectly normal.Can you please check it on your side?

```
//create geo coordinate

let geoCoordCenter = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: 49.260327, longitude: -123.115025)

//set map view with geo center

self.mapView.set(geoCenter: geoCoordCenter, animation: .none)

//set zoom level

self.mapView.zoomLevel = 13.2;


// set map circle
let circle = NMAMapCircle(geoCoordCenter)

circle.fillColor = UIColor.white

circle.lineColor = UIColor.red

circle.lineWidth = 10

circle.radius = 1000

self.mapView.add(mapObject: circle)
```

[image]